# How can I split a string with variate contents?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a set of information (data) such as below:

data1 = KRBRP0 29.18ZHSFP0 37.33

For splitting these information I use the following expression:

re.split('([a-zA-Z]{5}0\s*\d+.\d+)' , data2)

but in my data I have some with different pattern such as below:

data2 = EMG1P0119.44AFJ P0127.44KRBRP0 29.18ZHSFP0 37.33

Could you please let me which expression that I can use for splitting second pattern (data2)?

Thank you

Comment: What is the desired split? Can you add what you expect as output?

Comment: in second one, before "P0" there is "1" or space but in first one only alphabet. I expect: "KRBRP0 29.18" and "ZHSFP0 37.33", and for second one: "EMG1P0119.44"; "AFJ P0127.44"; "KRBRP0 29.18"; "ZHSFP0 37.33"

Answer (score 0):

You can use "OR" in regex with this pattern: (this|that). To not capture, you can use ?: inside the capturing-group, like this:

```
import re

data1 = "KRBRP0 29.18ZHSFP0 37.33"
data2 = "EMG1P0119.44AFJ P0127.44KRBRP0 29.18ZHSFP0 37.33"
regex = r"([a-zA-Z]*\s*(?:P0|1P0)\s*[0-9]+.[0-9]+)"
print re.findall(regex, data1)
print re.findall(regex, data2)

# Outputs:
# ['KRBRP0 29.18', 'ZHSFP0 37.33']
# ['EMG1P0119.44', 'AFJ P0127.44', 'KRBRP0 29.18', 'ZHSFP0 37.33']
```

But you don't even need to "OR", you could simply use another zero-or-more (*) of 1's, like with whitespace: `regex = r"([a-zA-Z]*\s*1*P0\s*[0-9]+.[0-9]+)"`.